# How can I make round field for board game Nip with pygame?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, math, pygame

I want to make round field for board game called Nip with pygame.
Reversi is traditionally played on a square board. The standard game board is an 8x8 grid. Nip is variation of Reversi which played on round board.

Here I set the game board. I did like this because I needed to track where is BLACK or WHITE disc placed through the game.

```py
EMPTY,CORNER = 0,0
BLACK = 1
WHITE = -1

board = [
    [      2,     2, CORNER, CORNER, CORNER, CORNER,     2,     2,],
    [      2, CORNER, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, CORNER,     2,], 
    [  CORNER, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, CORNER,], 
    [  CORNER, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK, WHITE, EMPTY, EMPTY, CORNER,], 
    [  CORNER, EMPTY, EMPTY, WHITE, BLACK, EMPTY, EMPTY, CORNER,], 
    [  CORNER, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, CORNER,], 
    [      2, CORNER, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, CORNER,     2,],
    [      2,     2, CORNER, CORNER, CORNER, CORNER,     2,     2,],
]
```

Then I tried to make cell for placing the disc like this

```
for row in range(ROWS):
    for col in range(COLS):
        if board[row][col] != 2 :
                    
            x = col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE // 2 
            y = row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE // 2

            # Draw the cell
            pygame.draw.circle(self.win, WHITE_COLOR, (x, y), PIECE_RADIUS//3, 2)
```

However this made hexagonal field. Then I tried to rearrange the CORNER cells in an outer circle to make round field with this code.

```
for i in range(0,360,THETA):
    pygame.draw.circle(self.win, (255,0,0), (400+380*math.cos(math.radians(i)), 400+380*math.sin(math.radians(i))), PIECE_RADIUS//3, 2)
```

Here I calculated THETA between adjacent cells and placed cells on outer circle. The center coordinates of outer circle is (400,400) and the radius is 380.

The output is  this
[image]

The white cells are the ones that were created at the beginning, and the red cells are the ones that I tried to make into an outer circle.

How can I make the outside round without disturbing the original rows and columns of cells?

[This is my full code.](https://github.com/igor-bond16/Nip/tree/main/Nip)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to test if a point is in a circle:

```py
import math
```

```py
max_distance = SQUARE_SIZE * 4
center_x = SQUARE_SIZE * 5
center_y = SQUARE_SIZE * 5

for row in range(ROWS):
    for col in range(COLS):
        
        x = col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE // 2 
        y = row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE // 2
        
        dx = x - center_x
        dy = y - center_y
        distance = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

        if distance < max_distance:
            ...
```